# What is the exact meaning of "Not like you hold me" in Michael Jackson's song "Love never felt so good"?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

```
Baby, love never felt so good 
And I doubt if it ever could 
Not like you hold me, hold me
```

I interpret the "Not like you hold me" part as

```
It's not like you hold me.
```

as same usage in "It's not like I've done anything wrong."

But a friend said to me that it is the abbreviation of

```
I'd not like you to hold me.
```

So I thought word 'like' is a conjunction, and a friend thought it is a verb.

Who is right? or Is neither of us wrong?

Comment: In standard English, it would be: I doubt I could ever not like you **holding** me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a continuation of the meaning of the first line, "Baby, love never felt so good".
So, "not like you hold me" means "Love never felt as good as it does now, when it is you who are holding me."

That's my sense about it, but looking for "exact meaning" in relation to these lyrics is probably a mistake. A good part of the lyrics of popular songs is intended to be suggestive or just to sound good when sung.

Comment: I got it. Thank you. 
Then, Is it natural to say "I never felt so good not like this." ?  And awkward to say "I never felt so good  like this." ?

Comment: You could say the first with a pause, indicated in writing with a comma  "I never felt so good, not like this." But it's not good written English. You second example here would be acceptable if it were "I never felt as good as this."

Comment: Then is second one acceptable in colloquial English?

Comment: Not as you wrote it, no.